# Why is my activity content not showing up?

Tags: android, android-activity

There's a problem specifically in one activity that keeps showing up with a blank screen. The heading shows up and the activity itself also shows up, but there are no contents.

This is the activity dashboardactivity:

```
package com.example.shashank.login;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String name, dropday, pickday, droptime, picktime;
    int phoneno;

    EditText nameInput;
    EditText dropdayInput;
    EditText pickdayInput;
    EditText droptimeInput;
    EditText picktimeInput;
    EditText phonenoInput;

    Button bookButton;


    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        nameInput = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        phonenoInput =  findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        dropdayInput =  findViewById(R.id.editDay1);
        pickdayInput =  findViewById(R.id.editDay2);
        droptimeInput = findViewById(R.id.editTime1);
        picktimeInput =  findViewById(R.id.editTime2);

        bookButton = findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        bookButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            name = nameInput.getText().toString();
            dropday = dropdayInput.getText().toString();
            pickday = pickdayInput.getText().toString();
            droptime = droptimeInput.getText().toString();
            picktime = picktimeInput.getText().toString();
            phoneno = Integer.parseInt(phonenoInput.getText().toString());

            showToast(name);
            showToast(String.valueOf(phoneno));
            showToast(dropday);
            showToast(pickday);
            showToast(droptime);
            showToast(picktime);
        });


    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.shashank.login.RegisterActivity">


    <TextView
        android:text="MAKE AN APPOINTMENT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_pet_s_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

    <!--space to insert date and time picker-->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDay1"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPhone"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_day_of_dropoff"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDay2"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPhone"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_day_of_pickup"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTime1"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editDay1"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_dropoff_time"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="time|text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTime2"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editDay2"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_pickup_time"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="time|text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTime1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_time_in_am_pm_format"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bookButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editDay1"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="@string/book_appointment"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bookButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/if_a_slot_is_not_available_for_you_at_this_selected_time_we_will_contact_you_and_reschedule_it"android:textColor="#FF0000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the manifest file if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/book_appointment"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />

    </application>
```

DashboardActivity shows up with its title but with no content within. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the crash (Exception and stack trace) from logcat.

Comment: Please attach your crash log